# I am trying to open 10 websocket connections with nodejs, but somehow my loop doesnt work

Tags: node.js

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {
    ws[i] = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9898/echo/websocket');   

    ws[i].on('open', function() {
        ws[i].send('why');
    });

}
```

I am trying to open 10 websocket connections with nodejs, but somehow my loop doesnt work.  What is wrong with my code?  Thanks

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `ws[i]` within the function.

Comment: That type of application you are making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Nitzan Shaked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523042/nitzan-shaked) says your issue is due to the loop problem. When the callbacks start to fire all the `i` values are `9` here.

#### generic solution

As a generic solution, solve it using a simple closure.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {

    ws[i] = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9898/echo/websocket');   
    ws[i].on('open', generator(ws[i]));

}

//generator makes a function with present object and returns it
var generator = function (k) {

    return function() {
        k.send('why');
    }

}
```

#### easy way

But the easiest way specific to your context would be by simply replacing `ws[i]` by a `this`

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {

    ws[i] = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9898/echo/websocket');   
    ws[i].on('open', function() {
         this.send('why');
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to the node.js. I eventually solved the problem with closures and starting to understand how to "cope" with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Classic Javascript loop gotcha. Look here: [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem).

Basically at the point where the callback is called, `ws[i].send(...)`, `i` refers to `i` at the *end* of the loop, not where you are defining the callback.

**EDIT** -- as Casey Chu noted, I have a silly bug in my code example. Instead of fixing it and coming up with a duplicate of other answers, I refer you to the (currently) 2 other answers which are perfectly working.

Comment: This doesn't work either, since `j` keeps on getting overwritten, too.